# now.js - Hello World example - "require not defined"

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

I'm having trouble getting the [now.js chat client tutorial](http://nowjs.com/examples/hw) to work. (I've also followed [this video](http://vimeo.com/20936525#at=0) almost exactly).

#### server.coffee:

```
fs = require 'fs'
http = require 'http'
now = require 'now'

server = http.createServer (req, res) ->
    fs.readFile(
        'index.html'
        (err, data) ->
            res.writeHead(
                200
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                )
            res.end(data)
        )
server.listen 8080

everyone = now.initialize(server)

everyone.now.distributeMessage = (msg) ->
    everyone.now.receiveMessage(@.now.name, msg)
```

#### index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>nowjs title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/Flotype/now/master/lib/now.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            now.name = prompt("What's your name?", "");
            now.receiveMessage = function(name, msg) {
              return $("<div></div>").text("" + name + ": " + msg).appendTo("#msg");
            };
            return $("#send-button").click(function() {
              now.distributeMessage($("#text-input").val());
              return $("#text-input").val("");
            });
          });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="msg"></div>

        <input type="text" id="text-input">
        <input type="button" value="Send" id="send-button">
    </body>
</html>
```

When I load up the server with `node server.js`,

I get an error that says "require not defined" on line 1 of now.js. Consequently, the client side code can't find the variable 'now'.

I understand that 'require' is a node function, but how do I get the client to understand that?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you install now.js with dependencies?

Comment: yep. I installed it with `npm install now`. Server.js has no issues finding 'now'.

Comment: I'm confused, are you getting the error `"require not defined" on line 1 of now.js` on the client or the server? Also you should be pulling the now.js file for your client off your node server and not a remote resource `/NowJS/now.js`

Comment: I'm getting the error on the client side. The server side is quiet. Does it make a difference where I get node.js from?

Comment: Wait, what magic is this? Changing the src to `/nowjs/now.js` fixed it. Where is the server getting this file from?

Comment: (Also, @travis do you want to answer the question with that comment so I can mark it as an answer?)

Comment: sure, writing it up now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you're including in your client source (`../Flotype/now/master/lib/now.js`) is the Node server side code that is included in your node process when calling `now = require 'now'`.

So changing your included client source file from `.../Flotype/now/master/lib/now.js` to `/nowjs/now.js` will fix your problem.

**Where does this /nowjs/now.js file come from?**

When using NowJS (and many other npm packages that do client/server communication) you extend the server object. This is done with the line `everyone = now.initialize(server)` ([Code Here](https://github.com/Flotype/now/blob/master/lib/now.js#L163)).

What the initialize function does is [wrap your server](https://github.com/Flotype/now/blob/master/lib/now.js#L181) with the `fileServer` ([Code Here](https://github.com/Flotype/now/blob/master/lib/fileServer.js)) class in NowJS. This adds a [resource under the "folder" nowjs](https://github.com/Flotype/now/blob/master/lib/fileServer.js#L36) which serves the client [now.js](https://github.com/Flotype/now/blob/master/lib/client/now.js) file.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to run nodejs file with js command instead of node. 
Eg: if the nodejs file name is test.js, I was doing

js test.js

instead of 
   node test.js

I hope this helps too for people searching for this error.